# Closed set $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\partial S = \{0\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be a closed set such that $0$ is its only boundary point. Does it follow that $S = \{0\}$?

**My attempt:**

Assume $S$ contains some $x \ne 0$. Then $S$ also contains some open ball around $x$.

We can consider $$r_{\text{max}} = \sup\{r > 0 : K(x,r) \subseteq S\}$$
and then $K(x, r_\text{max}) \subseteq S$. However, every point at the boundary of $S$ is either $0$ or it also must be in $S$. It seems intuitive that this must lead to a contradiction somehow.

However, probably some connectedness argument will come into play since the claim is false for $\mathbb{R}$, namely consider the set $[0, +\infty\rangle$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the intersection of your set $S$ with $Y := \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ 0 \}$. Then this is a closed subset of $Y$, and it is also an open subset in $Y$ (by our condition). Therefore, since $Y$ is connceted, this subset must be either equal to the whole $Y$, or be empty. If it is empty, this is what we want. If it is equal to the whole of $Y$, our set $S$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$, for which $0$ is clearly not a boundary point.

Comment: Thanks! This also shows why it doesn't work for $\mathbb{R}$ since $Y = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ is not connected.

Comment: Also, your proof works for $\Bbb{R}^n$ for $n\ge2$. Your argument was very elegant. Thanks for posting it! +1